# Swift confine protocol to certain types of class only

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I've got a protocol that I only assign to SKScene objects. It's basically so that I can enforce certain properties and methods allowing me to create a manager class knowing that my scenes can all do certain things. e.g So I can create a tutorial scene for instance and a level 1, level 2 etc.

```
  protocol GameSceneProtocol  {
        func performAction()
  }
```

So now in my manager I have a weak var for the scene (The manager is initialised in the scene)

```
 weak var scene: SKScene?
```

The issue I've got is that I want to call methods that relate to SKScene but also to my protocol. e.g

```
 scene.addChild(modal)
 scene.performAction()
```

What I really want to do is something like:

```
weak var scene: SKScene, GameSceneProtocol
```

The reason I'm using this manager is because I have a need to add different modal views to my scenes (again tutorials and levels) and then run common code based on actions taken in these modals. These modals and functionality are the same across the different scenes which is why I tried to move them to separate classes.

Is there a way I can ensure a property is of a certain type but also conforms to a protocol?

I've got a feeling my design is wrong up front here and there's probably a better way I should structure this. Possibly creating a base scene class that my actual scenes inherit from rather than a protocol. That way I can avoid duplicating the same code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is a subclass

```
class SKSceneWithProtocol : SKScene, GameSceneProtocol
```

but at this point the protocol is essentially pointless, and you may as well just do the code in the subclass instead.

Your other option is to cast the scene to the protocol when you need to use it

```
if let sceneProtocol = scene as? GameSceneProtocol
{
    //do stuff here
}
```

Comment: I just made an edit to my post saying that's what I probably should have done just as you posted! I think I just wanted to avoid rework - it's a hobby project that I didn't really plan the structure up front - that's come back to bite me!

Comment: It happens to all of us.

Answer (score 2):

You can use protocol composition to define a property where the object must be both an `SKScene` and a `GameSceneProtocol`. Since protocol compositions *only* work with protocols (not classes), you must also define an empty `SKSceneProtocol` and add that conformance to `SKScene` via an extension.

```
protocol SKSceneProtocol { }
extension SKScene: SKSceneProtocol { }

protocol GameSceneProtocol { ... }

var object: (SKSceneProtocol & GameSceneProtocol)? = nil
```

Comment: "Since protocol compositions only work with protocols (not classes), " Not true in Swift 4

Comment: Why woudn't you just extend SKScene to take the GameSceneProtocol at this point?

Comment: I gave you the up vote since I was never aware that this could be done with protocols, but I can't seem to get this working in a playground.  Could you provide a more elaborate example of it working please.